# Keras prediction error when stacking models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have 2 trained models: model_1 and model_2. I create a global model by stacking these two:

```html
inp = keras.layers.Input((50,50,11))
out_model1 = model_1(inp)
out_model2 = model_2(out_model1)
model_global = keras.models.Model(inp,out_model2)
```

I try 2 different predictions:

```html
out1 = model_1.predict(inp_data)
out2 = model_2.predict(out1)

out_global = model_global.predict(inp_data)
```

Then the result *out2* if different from *out_global*.

Could anyone explain why? (my keras version is 2.2.2)

Comment: Are you sure this, this is weird? Can you post complete code? And how much different these values are? This must be due to floating points.

Comment: Hi @Ankish Bansal, out2 and out_global are completely different.
All the data, variables used in my code are float32.

Comment: Any random layers? Noise generation, augmentation and other kinds of random operations in the model?

Comment: can you show what out1 and out2 are?

Comment: @Daniel Möller: no, model_1 and model_2 are pure conv2d, conv3d, reshape, LSTM, etc.
Thank you

Comment: @user1269942 they are remove sensing images, the images don't give you much information. Thank you

Comment: `stateful=True`, I presume....

Comment: No, I set stateful = False

Comment: Well... in that case I'm completely out of ideas. You should probably post your entire code. This result is very unusual and there is probably a problem somewhere else.

Comment: deepstack offers an interface for stacking Keras Models out of the box (https://github.com/jcborges/DeepStack)